# How is it possible that a strictly increasing function can be continuous?

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a strictly increasing function. Assume $f$ is continuous at $a$. Then $lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = f(a)$. However, since x approaches a from the left, shouldn't it be that $f(x)<f(a)$ for all $x$ since $f$ is strictly increasing? Then I don't understand how it is possible that $f$ can be continuous at $a$.

Comment: Note that $f(x) = x$ is continuous and strictly increasing.

Comment: It is possible for $f(x) < f(a)$ for all $x < a$, but for $\lim_{x\to a^{-}} f(x) = f(a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting confused about the terminology of limits.

In calculus, a single-variable real-valued function $f$ is called continuous at a point $a$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) = f(a) $
Consider this graph. You can see three different examples.

[image]

Source: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Continuity.aspx

- *Left example* As $x \rightarrow -2$ from the left, the limit is 2, but when approached from the right, the limit is -1. We call this "discontinuous" because these limits don't match. Visually, you can see when the limits don't match there's a giant jump in the graph -- a jump discontinuity.
- *Right example* if $x \rightarrow 3$ from either the left or right, the limits now match. Both of them have their limit at $f(3)=0$. The problem is, the point they approach isn't where the rest of the line is. By the way it's designed, that point is all the way at $-1$. This is called a point discontinuity.
- *Middle example* Notice at as $x\rightarrow 0$, you get $f(0) =1$ from either side. This is an example of "continuity" and, intuitively, the curve looks continuous.

I hope this helps you see the intuition better.

Now consider a simple function like $f(x)=x$. In this case, $f$ won't actually equal $f(a)$ until you plug in $a$. There isn't a bunch of points near $a$ which are equal to $f(a)$. So it makes sense that $f(x) < f(a)$ but then suddenly equals $f(x) = f(a)$ when $x=a$. This "sudden change" doesn't make it "discontinuous." Just like in the graph, what matters is the behavior of the function prior to reaching that point and then also at that point.   But you know intuitively, 
\begin{align*}
4 + .75 &= 4.75\\
4+ 0.9 &= 4.9\\
4 + 0.999 &= 4.999\\
\end{align*}
In other words, if we have $4 + \epsilon$, and we let $\epsilon = 1$, then $x + \epsilon = 5$. It's not sudden. There's no issue. It's a natural consequence of actually landing on $\epsilon = 1$ after trying out all the numbers of $\epsilon$ less than $1$.

Thus, 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon  \to 1^-} 4 + \epsilon =5 $$

"Strictly increasing" just means that, if $x$ goes up, $f(x)$ will too. This doesn't affect the limit since you are by nature picking a particular point that you are examining the limit with respect to. So approaching that point $x\rightarrow a$ will of course make the function approach a particular point too.

Answer (score 1):

$1-\frac 1 n <1$ for all $n$ but that doesn't mean $\lim (1-\frac  1 n) <1$. Less than becomes an equality in the limit. Same situation with your case. Though  $f(x) <f(a)$ for  $x<a$ you can get equality in the limit.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a rigorous way of explaining why you can "get equality in the limit"?

Comment: @ddnk How about pondering the example of Arctic Char?

Comment: If you are asking for a proof of the fact that $\lim (1-\frac 1 n)=1$ just note that $|(1-\frac 1 n )-1| <\epsilon$ whenever $n >\frac 1 {\epsilon}$.

Comment: @ddnk It sounds like you should review the [definition of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit).